# reading an array from a text file?

Tags: vb.net, console, console-application, vb.net-2010

```
Imports System.IO
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim readers As New StreamReader("input.txt")
        Dim s As String
        Dim a() As String
        Dim b(,) As Integer
        Dim count As Integer = 0

        s = readers.ReadLine
        Do
            s = readers.ReadLine
            If s <> "" Then
                a = Split(s, ",")
                ReDim Preserve b(count, a.Length - 1)
                fill2darr(a, b, count)
                count += 1
            End If
            s = readers.ReadLine
        Loop While s <> " "

        Dim temp() As Integer = TransferTo1D(b)
        SelectionSort(temp)
        TransferTo2D(b, temp)
        writeintofile(b)

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
    Public Sub fill2darr(ByVal a() As String, ByRef b(,) As Integer, ByVal counter As Integer)
        For i = 0 To a.Length - 1
            b(counter, i) = Val(a(i))
        Next
    End Sub
    Public Function TransferTo1D(ByRef B(,) As Integer) As Integer()
        Dim ARR1D(B.Length - 1) As Integer, e As Integer = 0
        For i = 0 To B.GetUpperBound(0)
            For j = 0 To B.GetUpperBound(1)
                ARR1D(e) = B(i, j)
                e += 1
            Next
        Next
        Return ARR1D
    End Function
    Public Sub SelectionSort(ByRef arr1d() As Integer)
        Dim i, j, min, temporary As Integer
        For i = 0 To arr1d.GetUpperBound(0)
            min = i
            For j = i + 1 To arr1d.GetUpperBound(1)
                If (arr1d(j) < arr1d(min)) Then
                    min = j
                End If
            Next
            temporary = arr1d(i)
            arr1d(i) = arr1d(min)
            arr1d(min) = temporary
        Next
    End Sub
    Public Sub TransferTo2D(ByRef twodarray(,) As Integer, ByRef onedarray() As Integer)
        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        For i = 0 To twodarray.GetUpperBound(0)
            For j = 0 To twodarray.GetUpperBound(1)
                If counter < onedarray.Length Then
                    twodarray(i, j) = onedarray(counter)
                    counter = counter + 1
                Else
                    twodarray(i, j) = 0
                End If
            Next
        Next

    End Sub
    Public Sub writeintofile(ByVal b(,) As Integer)
        Dim writer As New StreamWriter("output.txt")
        For i = 0 To b.GetUpperBound(0)
            For j = 0 To b.GetUpperBound(1)
                writer.Write(b(i, j))
                writer.Write(",")

            Next
            writer.WriteLine()
        Next

    End Sub
End Module
```

This is a program I wrote for reading values from a text file and arrange it in two dimension array then transfer it to one D array to sort it in the right way from minimum value to the maximum and lastly to reprint it in another text file. this code above don't have any errors but its written for reading one array from a text file , i want the program whenever it reads the word "array:" do the steps of transferring ,sorting and reprinting the resulted array in the "output" text file and after that it empty the array so it could receive the next array , i'm not sure how can i write this condition , any suggestion?

Comment: Don't use an array. `Redim Preserve` creates a new array each time and copies the contents of the old array into the new array. Use a `List(Of Integer())`, i.e. a list of arrays instead. Don't forget to close and dispose the `StreamWriter`. You can do it with the `Using` statement. See the example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes i'm not used to work with lists , do i have to change a lot of things if i used list instead ? anyway thank you for the link and the help so much.

Comment: Instead of using just "output.txt" as the filename, you could try adding the whole path for example "c:\test\output.txt". Of course you'll need to change the directory path to a suitable one for you.

Comment: also, you'll need to add `Writer.Close` after the For..Next loop.

Comment: got it ,thanks.it worked out @DavidWilson